# Add link button does not work properly for wysiwyg editor in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, wysiwyg

The wysiwyg runs smoothly in chrome but in Firefox & IE11(not an old one), whenever I click on the add link button, the focus gets shifted to the main editor. I tried many workarounds like manipulating the CSS, stopping the event propagation on click of the input Add link input, but nothing seems to work.

Open link http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/ in IE11, click on add link icon then click on the URL box and then try to enter anything

I've added a workaround for Firefox(which run on document load), but it still does not work for IE.

```
msieVersion() {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./) || typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined')  // If Internet Explorer, return version number
    {   
        $('a.essay-btn').on('click', function(e){
            let self= $(this).closest('.hero-unit');
            self.find('.add_link').show();

            return false;
        })

        let span2 = '<a href="http://" style="color:#b0281a">http://</a>';

        $('.span2').on('keyup', function(f) { 
            span2 = '<a href="'+this.value+'" style="color:#b0281a">'+this.value+'</a>';
            return false;
        })

        $('.essay-btn-add').on('click', function(g){
            let self= $(this).closest('.hero-unit');
            let editor = self.find('.editor');
            editor.html(editor.html()+span2);
            self.find('.add_link').hide();
        return false; 
         })    
    }
    else  // If another browser, return 0
    {
        // alert('otherbrowser');
        return false;
    }
}
```